# Simple TabbedPage example

Tags: .net, xaml, maui

Where can I find a working TabbedPage example? I have tried converting the new .NET maui app from a ContentPage to a TabbedPage and although it compiles it gets an exception upon starting.

Comment: Exception code 0xc000027b if that helps

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/pages/tabbedpage